# CDbCriteria and mysql USE INDEX()

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I got problem with `active record` in `yii`. So the basic problem is how to define `USE INDEX()` mySQL criteria as CDbCriteria to pass it to CActivedataprovider.
I didn't find it in api or in code. Maybe someone already had this problem before and can share his solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1385 this hack helps with simple selects and indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use yii2 you can do it like this:

```
$yourQuery = YourModel::find()
        ->select(['*'])
        ->from(['yourTable USE INDEX(index1, index2, index3)']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do for AR. You should rewrite your code to [DAO](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao).

Comment: I know that there is no such method.